# Difference between db.isopen and db != null

Tags: java, lotus-notes

what is actually the difference between db.isopen and db != null or can I use them in combination and in which recommended logical order?

e.g.

```
Database db = null;
    try {
        Session sess = NotesPlatform.getInstance().getSession();
        db = sess.getDatabase(XPagesDataUtil.getServerName(server), database);
        if (!db.isOpen()) {
            try {
                db.open();
            } catch (NotesException ne) {
                if (StringUtil.equals(DominoUtil.LOCAL_CLIENT, server)) {
                    die[0] = new DominoImportException(ne, "Unable to find Views in the database: " + database);
                } else {
                    db = sess.getDatabase(XPagesDataUtil.getServerName(DominoUtil.LOCAL_CLIENT), database);
                    if (!db.isOpen()) {
                        db.open();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically I want to log if users access a database they do not have access to due to some reasons:

```
try {
    Database db = null;
    db = Utils.getSession().getDatabase(sName, dbName);
    if (!db.isOpen()){              
        try{
            db.open();              
        }catch(NotesException e){
            OpenLogUtil.logEvent(null, "User " + Utils.getSession().getEffectiveUserName() + " has unsufficient access for db:" + db.getFileName(), Level.INFO, null);
        }               
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    OpenLogUtil.logErrorEx(e, JSFUtil.getXSPContext().getUrl().toString(), Level.SEVERE, null);
}
//my business logic here
```

It looks like the combination to check if a database exists and if the user has sufficient access to it does not work as expected?

Comment: Well, the "logical" order would be to call `db != null` before `db.isOpen()` since you'd get a NPE otherwise. Besides that I as a non-expert would say that if `db` is null initialization didn't work at all while if it isn't you have a basic connection but might not be able to use it if `db.isOpen()` returns false.

Comment: `db` is a reference to an Object.   As such it could be in a null; this doesn't tell you anything about the database just that the reference to the database is null.  The database itself maybe available or unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ISOPEN_PROPERTY.html)

```
db.isOpen
```

checks that the db is open and ready for use in the Lotus Notes domain.

```
db != null
```

checks that db is ready for use in the Java domain.

i.e. you can't use `db.isOpen` if `db` is `null`

```
db = sess.getDatabase
```

ensures `db` will not be `null` as [getDatabase](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_10.0.0/basic/H_GETDATABASE_METHOD.html) says it doesn't return null if it fails so checking for null isn't required:

> If the database cannot be opened and createonfail is True or omitted,
>   IsOpen is false

so the docs effectively say that checking for null isn't required as `db.isOpen` will be either `true` or `false` depending whether the database was accessed or not.